# Inserting text into a varchar which happens to contain sql in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, string, quoting

I'm trying to **insert text which happens to contain a sql query** into a varchar, but MySQL is producing an error when I execute the insert. How can I accomplish this without producing an error?

Here's what I have so far. I created a table called "info":

```
CREATE TABLE  `info`.`sample` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `one_query` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

And then I try to insert the data:

```
insert into info.sample (one_query) values ('select u.county_id, u.name from sample.upfall u')
```

This produces the error message, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that... blah blah not very helpful." I think MySQL may be looking at my text as an actual select query, which it's trying to execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're using a reserved word. Are there any other fields in your table you're not telling us about?

Comment: Yes! I am using 'desc' which is also reserved. I changed it to 'descr' and it works fine now. This is why alcohol and computer programming don't mix.

Comment: While more of a question than an answer, enough breadcrumbs exist here that show this solved the problem, as well as what the problem was.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the table part to be

```
info.sample
```

or could it be just

```
sample
```